# Ubuntu Server Raid 0 Install Question

Tags: raid

I have installed Ubuntu -1410-utopic-64-minimal on my server. I have 2 3 TB HDDs. I installed in raid 0. This was my first time setti8ng up a raid. I don't know if I did it right. This is what shows up in Webmin.

http://gyazo.com/0136d4901627423d19e76d09c5c6851d

http://gyazo.com/64b607a6c4120ef4819d52c97c83f4d2

I fully understand and accept the risks of raid 0.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I want to know if I have everything configured correctly so that my 2 HDDs are acting as one.

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it clearer that that is what you are asking? Thanks! I'm saying this because that will help the community to answer your question more easily.

Answer (score 0):

firefox crashes when trying to follow your links... Try to put more info in your question. How are you configuring the raid? With a controller? Booting from raid is not only risky, but a pain in the you know what. suggest getting another drive - cheap is ok - boot from that then configure your other two drives as a raid array.